# Change Spring input validation language

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot

I have a web application that exposes RESTful services with Spring Boot.
I added validation on my models with the Hibernate implementation.
Example :

```
public class PersonForm {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Min(18)
    private Integer age;
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the messages are rendered in english.
Question : how can I force the application to render the messages in french ?

Regards.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add a spring bean in the context to set the default localization

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
    return slr;
}
```

Comment: @Liam: Did the answer help?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. It didn't work and it's still retrieving the messages in english. In the HIbernate validator JAR, the French messages are in the resources folder as well as the English, Chinese and other ones.

Comment: Worked so well for me ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In webflux，there is no SessionLocaleResolver, I simply add this:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
```

you can also set `-Duser.language=en`。

both works for me!